# The interaction between the encoder and the servo Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, schematics, servo, encoder, proteus

Why when the turn occurs in the + direction, it is also read -. Assignment: reading of the encoder occurs with a period of 100 mc, when the encoder rotation is detected the servo also rotates by 2 degrees in the corresponding direction.
Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;

unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long loopTime;
const int pin_A = 12;
const int pin_B = 11;
int encoder_A;
int encoder_B;
int encoder_B_prev = 0;
const int servoMid = 90;
int servoStep = 2;
int servoPos = servoMid;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 100;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin_A, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_B, INPUT);
  myservo.attach(9);
  myservo.write(servoMid);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    encoder_A = digitalRead(pin_A);
    encoder_B = digitalRead(pin_B);

    if (encoder_B != encoder_B_prev && encoder_B == 1) {
      if (encoder_A != encoder_B) {
        if (servoPos < 1) {
          servoPos = 0;
        }else{
           servoPos -= servoStep;          
        }
      }
      else {
        if (servoPos > 179) {
          servoPos = 180;
        }else{
          servoPos += servoStep;
        }
      }
    }
Serial.ptintln(servoPos);
myservo.write(servoPos); 
  encoder_B_prev = encoder_B; 
}
```

}

The result of changing the servoPos variable if the rotation is only +(output every 100 ms):
92
92
94
94
94
94
90
90
90
88
88
88
88
88
88
88
90
90
90
90
90
90
90
92
92
92
92
92
92
92
94
94
94
94
94
94
96
96
96
98
98
98
98
100
100
100
100
98
98
Schema proteus:

[image]

Comment: Please ask a question and edit your post

Comment: `Why when the turn occurs in the + direction, it is also read -?` ... because you read the encoder data at a fixed interval ... the encoder could be in any position when it is sampled ... imagine a camera that takes a picture of a stopwatch every 59 seconds ... the resulting images would show that the second hand is moving backward

Comment: `Assignment: reading of the encoder occurs with a period of 100 mc, when the encoder rotation is detected the servo also rotates by 2 degrees in the corresponding direction.` ... is this a school assignment? .... is that really the assignment, word for word? ... as it is worded, it makes no sense, because it will fail